# How to make complexType empty or with no more than 100 values?

Tags: xml, xsd

Once again I could use your help, with XML Schema this time...
This is the exercise I have to do:

Define an XML Schema which describes an hotel.

```
Document's root is "hotel" element and it has following other elements:
1)name <hotel's name type:string>
2)rooms <list of "type" elements, which can be empty but with not more  
         than 100 elements of type RoomType which contain: 
                1)type <room's type, it's value is one of {single, double,triple}>
                2)number <number of rooms of specified type in the hotel>
3)forSmokers<optional element, number of rooms where smokers are allowed>
```

This is my code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name = "hotel">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name = "rooms" type = "roomType"/>
                <xs:element name = "forSmokers" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name = "roomType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "room'stype" type = "roomTypes" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "100"/>
                <xs:element name = "number" type = "xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "100"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleType name = "roomTypes">
            <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value = "single"/>
                <xs:enumeration value = "double"/>
                <xs:enumeration value = "triple"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now with this XML file, Validation goes well:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<hotel>
    <name>NomeHotel</name>
    <rooms>
        <room'stype>singola</room'stype>
        <number>1</number>
    </rooms>
    <forSmokers>22</forSmokers>
</hotel>
```

My issue is: 
Right now, if I add `<room'stype>`and `<number` tag in existing `<rooms>` tag, Validation returns error.
I need rooms tag to allow 0 elements (so it can be empty) but it cannot have more than 100 elements, how do I have to modify code in order to achieve that?

Sorry for long question, just wanted to be clear.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your schema to this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name = "hotel">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name = "rooms" type = "roomType"/>
                <xs:element name = "forSmokers" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name = "roomType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "roomstype" type = "roomTypes" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "100"/>
                <xs:element name = "number" type = "xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "100"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleType name = "roomTypes">
            <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value = "singola"/>
                <xs:enumeration value = "double"/>
                <xs:enumeration value = "triple"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have noticed two things:

1. element names cannot contain `'`
2. in the xml there is `singola`, but in the schema was `single`

Answer (score 0):

XML element names may not contain apostrophe characters.

Change `room'stype` to `roomsType` or just `type`, since context should make it clear that it's the type of the room.

Also note:  You've not yet added `RoomType` to your XML.